# Derive parametric equations for sphere

Tags: geometry, parametric

How do you derive the parametric equations for a sphere?
\begin{align}
x & = r \cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi), \\
y & = r \sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi), \\
z & = r \cos(\varphi),
\end{align}
where $\theta$ is from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $\varphi$ is from $0$ to $\pi$.
There are no good explanations online.

Comment: What about [$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z^2%2By^2%2Bx^2%3D1)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Answer (score 11):

If you're familiar with [surfaces of revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution), the derivation is easy. A circle that is rotated around a diameter generates a sphere.

The parametric equations for a surface of revolution are:

$$
\left(f(u)\cos v, f(u)\sin v, g(u)\right)
$$

Where $\left(f(u), g(u)\right)$ are the parametric equations of the rotated curve. For a circle, they are $\left(r \cos u, r \sin u\right)$. Therefore, the parametric equations of a sphere are:

$$
\left(r \cos u \cos v, r \cos u \sin v, r \sin u\right)
$$

Change the variables from $(u, v)$ to $(\frac{\pi}{2} - \varphi, \theta)$ to get the equations in your question.

Comment: What is the axis of revolution here?

Comment: It is the $z$-axis. Indeed, the parametric equation of the rotated curve would be $\left( x,y,z\right)=\left(f(u), 0,g(u)\right)$ I guess.

Answer (score 2):

$\phi$ is the angle which polar radius makes with the $z$ axis. Hence, multiplying by $\sin \phi$ you find the projection of the polar radius on the $xy$ plane. Then multiplying by $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ respectively you find projections on axes $x$ and $y$

Answer (score 0):

I thought that it would be interesting to parameterise a sphere by using only 2 parameters $r$ and $\theta$ as follows
\begin{align}
x&=r\sin(\theta)\cos(n\theta),\\
y&=r\sin(\theta)\sin(n\theta),\\
z&=r\cos(\theta),
\end{align}
where $\theta$ is from $0$ to $\pi$ and $n$ is a reasonably large integer e.g. 64.
This results in a spiraling curve which describes a sphere with radius r. Check out the visualisation [here](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/snkd7ah3).