# On Lagrange Multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I only recently started studying the Lagrange Multipliers, and was given a task to create some challenging problems on them and also provide solutions. Could somebody please suggest how I could get started on this? Some example problems would be welcome!

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you searched the site? Running the risk of excessive self-promotion I rather liked [this trick](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/428978/11619). Not sure whether I would call it very hard though.

Comment: You can use `<br>` or `<hr>` to separate parts of the text. See [editing help](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, here's 2:

a really good one to start out with is the optimization problem behind Principal Component Analysis.

$$\text{max$_{\bf v}$ } \langle \bf{v},\Sigma_n \bf{v}\rangle$$ $$\text {s.t.}$$ $$||\bf {v}||_2=1$$

where $\bf v$ is a vector and $\Sigma_n= \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n(\bf x_i -\mu_n)(\bf x_i - \mu_n)^T$ is the Covariance matrix of the data points $\bf x_i$

The answer for $\bf v$ is the vector that points in the direction of the eigenvector of $\Sigma_n$ corresponding to its largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{max}$

Another really good application of Lagrange multipliers/ difficult problem involving Lagrange multipliers is solving for the Euler equation in Economics for logarithmic utility. This is extremely important in the theory of dynamic programming as well.

$$max \sum_{t=0}^{T-1} lnc_t + lnx_T$$ $$\text{s.t.}$$ $$x_{t+1} =\alpha (x_t-c_t)$$

Be careful, $x_t$ shows up twice. Interpret as maximizing consumption and final wealth where $x_t$ is the wealth at period $t$ with $t=0$ corresponding to initial wealth and $c_t$ is the consumption for period $t$.

The solution is: $x_t^*=\frac {T+1-t}{T+1}(\frac 1{\alpha})^{-t}x_0$ and $c_t^*=\frac {(\frac 1{\alpha})^{-t}x_0}{T+1}$

These two problems include applications of lagrange multipliers to 1. a problem involving matrix calculus. and 2. a problem in which an optimal consumption path is determined (function), which has ties to optimal control and the functional optimization.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a moderately complicated example, cooked up in such a way that it can be solved explicitly all the way to the end.

Given are the two points $A=(0,-7)$,  $B=(-7,0)$, and the circle $\gamma: \>x^2+y^2=4$. Determine two points $P$, $Q\in\gamma$ such that the quantity
$$d(P,Q):=|AP|^2+|PQ|^2+|QB|^2$$
becomes maximal, resp., minimal.

[image]

You will obtain four conditionally stationary situations $(P_k,Q_k)$: the two extremal situations and two "saddle points". The latter had to be expected, since the surface determined by the conditions is a torus.

A full solution (in German) is given on pp. 212–214 of the following pdf-file. The file contains a full chapter (pages 128–236) of a textbook for engineering students. *Scroll down* to page 212; there you will see the figure printed above.

https://people.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/Inganalysis_5.pdf

Comment: This file is one long webpage with page numbers and headers for every included book page from 128 to 236. You cannot access page 212 by typing 212 somewhere. Scroll down until you get to page 212. I won't go into fabricating a translation.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter , very interesting problem. Where did you get inspired to create it? How did you formulate this question ? What was your thought process ?

Comment: @danilocn94: I wanted a problem with two conditions but no boundaries to inspect. Then the setup should be as simple as possible, no square roots at the beginning of the computation, and "small numbers" in the result. A lot of "reverse engineering" went into the final version of this problem.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter , what I'd like to know is about the geometry of the problem. How did you formulate this question (geometrically) ? What were your inspiration and thought process ?

Comment: @danilocn94: I cannot say more than I have written in my last comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here two other ones :

**Exercice 1 :**

> Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$. For all $\left(x,y,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$, find the optimal constant $C\left(\alpha\right)\in\mathbb{R}$
>     such that $$x^{3}-\left(\frac{z}{\alpha}\right)^{3}\leq C\left(\alpha\right)\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{3/2}$$
>    and precise the case of equality in term of $\alpha$.

**Solution :**

We notice that the both sizes of the above equation are homogeneous functions of degree $3$ : it suffices to consider the problem on the unit sphere $\mathcal{S}=\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3};x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1\right\}$.
Soient $f$ et $g$ the functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ by $$\begin{cases}
f\left(x,y,z\right)=x^{3}-\left(\frac{z}{\alpha}\right)^{3}\\
g\left(x,y,z\right)=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-1
\end{cases}.$$

As $f$ is continuous and $\mathcal{S}$ is compact, $f_{\mid\mathcal{S}}$ is bounded and attain its maximum values. 
For all $\left(x,y,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$, we have
$$\begin{cases}
\mathrm{d}f\left(x,y,z\right)=3x^{2}dx-3\frac{z^{2}}{\alpha^{3}}dz\\
\mathrm{d}g\left(x,y,z\right)=2xdx+2ydy+2zdz
\end{cases}$$
or in matricial notations in the basis $\left(\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}y,\mathrm{d}z\right)$
  of $\left(\mathbb{R}^{3}\right)^{*}$

$$\begin{pmatrix}3x^{2} & 0 & -3\frac{z^{2}}{\alpha^{3}}\\
2x & 2y & 2z
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Cancelling all the $\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\end{pmatrix}=3$ $2\times2$-determinants so that $\mathrm{d}f\left(x,y,z\right)$ and $\mathrm{d}g\left(x,y,z\right)$ are linearly dependant yields :

$$\begin{vmatrix}3x^{2} & 0\\
2x & 2y
\end{vmatrix}=6x^{2}y=0\Longleftrightarrow\left(x=0\right)\textrm{ ou }\left(y=0\right).$$
$$ \begin{vmatrix}3x^{2} & -3\frac{z^{2}}{\alpha^{3}}
2x & 2z
\end{vmatrix}=6xz\left(x+\frac{z}{\alpha^{3}}\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow\left(x=0\right)\textrm{ ou }\left(z=0\right)\textrm{ ou }\left(x=-\frac{z}{\alpha^{3}}\right).$$
 $$\begin{vmatrix}0 & 3\frac{z^{2}}{\alpha^{3}}\\
2y & 2z
\end{vmatrix}=6y\frac{z^{2}}{\alpha^{3}}=0\Longleftrightarrow\left(y=0\right)\textrm{ ou }\left(z=0\right).$$

Then, for all $\left(x,y,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$ :

$(i)$ if $\alpha<1$, $$f\left(x,y,z\right)\leq\frac{1}{\alpha^{3}}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{3/2}$$
with equality iff $\left(x,y,z\right)\in\left\{ \left(0,0,-\lambda\right);\lambda\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}\right\}$ ;

$(ii)$ if $\alpha=1$, $$f\left(x,y,z\right)\leq\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{3/2}$$
with equality iff $\left(\left(x,y,z\right)\in\left\{ \left(\lambda,0,0\right);\lambda\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}\right\} \right)$
  or $\left(\left(x,y,z\right)\in\left\{ \left(0,0,-\lambda\right);\lambda\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}\right\} \right)$ ;

$(iii)$ If $\alpha>1$,
 $$f\left(x,y,z\right)\leq\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{3/2}$$
with equality iff $\left(x,y,z\right)\in\left\{ \left(\lambda,0,0\right);\lambda\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}\right\} $.

**Exercice 2 :**

> Let $n$,$\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$, $1\leq\alpha\leq n$.
>   For all $\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, find the optimal constant $C\left(n,\alpha\right)\in\mathbb{R}$ such that 
>   $$x_{1}\ldots x_{n}\leq C\left(n,\alpha\right)\left(x_{1}^{\alpha}+\ldots+x_{n}^{\alpha}\right)^{n/\alpha}$$
>   and precise the case of equality in term of $\alpha$.

**Solution :**

We notice that the both sizes of the above equation are homogeneous functions of degree $n$ : it suffices to consider the problem on the hypersurface $\mathcal{S}=\left\{ \left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n};x_{1}^{\alpha}+\ldots+x_{n}^{\alpha}=1\right\}$.
Let $f$ and $g$ the functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by

$$\begin{cases}
f\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)=x_{1}\ldots x_{n}\\
g\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)=x_{1}^{\alpha}+\ldots+x_{n}^{\alpha}-1
\end{cases}.$$

We can assume that $x_{j}>0$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$ (the inequality is stronger in the case where there is an even number of $x_j<0$, which is the same that consider them all non-negative).
For all $\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$, we have

$$\begin{cases}
df\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\prod_{k\neq j}x_{k}\right)dx_{j}\\
dg\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)=\alpha\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(x_{j}^{\alpha-1}\right)dx_{j}
\end{cases}$$
 or in matricial notations

$$\begin{pmatrix}x_{2}x_{3}\ldots x_{n} & x_{1}x_{3}x_{4}\ldots x_{n} & \cdots & x_{1}x_{2}\ldots x_{n-2}x_{n-1}\\
\alpha x_{1}^{\alpha-1} & \alpha x_{2}^{\alpha-1} & \cdots & \alpha x_{n}^{\alpha-1}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

We cancel all the $\begin{pmatrix}n\\2\end{pmatrix}$ $2\times2$-determinants  so that $\mathrm{d}f\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)$ and $\mathrm{d}g\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)$ linearly dependant : for all $1\leq k$, $\ell\leq n$ with $k\neq\ell$, 
$$\begin{vmatrix}x_{1}\ldots x_{k-1}x_{k+1}x_{n} & x_{1}\ldots x_{\ell-1}x_{\ell+1}\ldots x_{n}\\
\alpha x_{k}^{\alpha-1} & \alpha x_{\ell}^{\alpha-1}
\end{vmatrix}=\alpha x_{1}\ldots x_{k-1}x_{k+1}\ldots x_{\ell-1}x_{\ell+1}\ldots x_{n}\left(x_{\ell}^{\alpha}-x_{k}^{\alpha}\right)=0
 \Longleftrightarrow x_{k}=x_{\ell}\Longrightarrow x_{1}=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}$$
 with the constraint $g\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)=0$.
 We get $$f\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}},\ldots,\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{\alpha}}$$
 and hence $$f_{\mid\mathcal{S}}\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)\leq\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha}}.$$
 We extend this result by homothetie to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ : 
 for all $\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $$x_{1}\ldots x_{n}\leq\left(\frac{x_{1}^{\alpha}+\ldots+x_{n}^{\alpha}}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{\alpha}}$$
 with equality iff $x_{1}=\ldots=x_{n}$.

Comment: @BetterWorld The optimal constant means the smallest one such that the above equalities hold.