# Range of $xyz\;,$ If $x+y+z=4$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=6$

Tags: calculus

> If $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x+y+z=4$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=6\;,$ Then range of $xyz$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$Using $$(x+y+z)^2=x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)$$

So we get $$16=6+2(xy+yz+zx)\Rightarrow xy+yz+zx = -5$$ and given $x+y+z=4$

Now let $xyz=c\;,$ Now leyt $t=x,y,z$ be the roots of cubic equation, Then

$$\displaystyle (t-x)(t-y)(t-z)=0\Rightarrow t^3-(x+y+z)t^2+(xy+yz+zx)t-xyz = 0$$

So we get $\displaystyle t^3-4t^2-5t-c=0$

Now let $f(t)=t^3-4t^2-5t-c\;,$ Then $f'(t)=3t^2-8t-5$

and $f''(t)=6t-8.$ Now for max. and Min.$f'(t)=0\Rightarrow 3t^2-8t-5=0$

So we get $\displaystyle t=\frac{8\pm \sqrt{64+60}}{2\cdot 3}=$

Now How can I solve it after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: You have a sign error early on, $xy+yz+zx=5$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425187/abc-0-a2b2c2-1-prove-that-a2-b2-c2-le-frac154

Comment: The corrected cubic equation $ \ t^3 \ - \ 4t^2 \ + \ 5t \ - \ c \ = \ 0 \ $ should lead you to $$ \ t \ = \ \frac{8 \ \pm \ \sqrt{64 \ - \ 60 }}{6} \ \ =  \ \ \frac{4 \ \pm \ 1}{3} \ \ = \ \ 1 \ , \ \frac{5}{3} $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ c \ = \ 2 \ \ , \ \ \frac{50}{27} $$ as the extremal values, with which a two-constraint Lagrange-multiplier computation (which I made) and WolframAlpha concur.  So you are nearly home.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By CS inequality we get
$$|x^3+y^3+z^3|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\sqrt{x^4+y^4+z^4}\tag{1}$$
Where
\begin{align*}
x^4+y^4+z^4&=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2-2[(xy+yz+xz)^2-2xy^2z-2xyz^2-2x^2yz]\\
&=36-2[5^2-2xyz(4)]\\
x^4+y^4+z^4&=16xyz-14\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Now, from the identity
$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)$$
follows 
\begin{align*}
x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz&=(4)(6-5)\\
x^3+y^3+z^3&=3xyz+4\tag{3}
\end{align*}
$(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ imply
\begin{align*}
|3xyz+4|\le\sqrt{6}\sqrt{16xyz-14}
\end{align*}
By setting $t=xyz$ and squaring the last inequality we get
$$9t^2+24t+16\le 96t-84\quad\iff\quad 9t^2-72t+100\le0\quad\iff\quad(3t-12)^2-44\le0$$
So 
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{4-\frac23\sqrt{11}\le xyz\le4+\frac23\sqrt{11}}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$c=t((t-2)^2+1),\ t\in \mathbb{R}$$, so according to the calculations, $c\in [a,b]$ where $$a=t((t-2)^2+1)|_{t=5/3}=\frac{50}{27},\ b=t((t-2)^2+1)|_{t=1}=2$$

Comment: It has been commented subsequently that OP made a small error in constructing the cubic polynomial, rendering the quadratic factor irreducible over $ \ \mathbb{R} \ $ .

Comment: Oh, right, It slipped my mind. I will make the necessary changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I thought it might be worth showing the Lagrange-multiplier method applied to this problem, largely for illustrating how the system of "Lagrange equations" can be handled, and for showing the interesting character of the solution.

With the constraints $ \ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ + \ z^2 \ = \ 6 \ $ and $ \ x \ + \ y \ + \ z \ = \ 4 \ $ on the function $ \ f (x, \ y, \ z ) \ = \ xyz \ $ , the equations using two "multipliers" are

$$ yz \ = \ \lambda \cdot  2x \ + \ \mu \cdot 1 \ \ , \ \ xz \ = \ \lambda \cdot  2y \ + \ \mu \cdot 1 \ \ , \ \ xy \ = \ \lambda \cdot  2z \ + \ \mu \cdot 1 \ \ , $$

permitting us to write

$$ \mu \ = \ yz \ - \ 2 \lambda x \ = \ xz \ - \ 2 \lambda y \ = \ xy \ - \ 2 \lambda z \   \ . $$

Re-arranging the first implied equation produces

$$ \ (y \ - \ x) \ z \ + \ (y \ - \ x ) \ 2 \lambda \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (y \ - \ x) \ ( z \ + \ 2 \lambda) \ = \ 0 \ \ ; $$

the other equated pairs of terms give us similar relations.

One solution then is to use $ \ x \ = \ y \ \ , \ \ x \ = \ z \ \ , $ and $ \ y \ = \ z \ $ in turn to obtain from the constraint equations

$$ x \ + \ x \ + \ z \ = \ 4 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x^2 \ + \ x^2 \ + \ ( 4 \ - \ 2x)^2 \ = \ 6x^2 \ - \ 16x \ + \ 16 \ = \ 6 $$
$$ 3x^2 \ - \ 8x \ + \ 5 \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ \frac{4 \ \pm \ 1}{3} \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ \ \frac{5}{3} \ \ , $$

as already described in the comments for the posted question, which the corrected cubic equation of OP would yield.  So we find three ordered triples, $ ( 1, \ 1, \ 2) \ , \ ( 1, \ 2, \ 1) \ , $ and $ \ ( 2, \ 1, \ 1) \ $ which give the same value of $ \ 2 \ $ for $ \ xyz \ $ and another three, 
$ ( \frac{5}{3}, \ \frac{5}{3}, \ \frac{2}{3}) \ , \ ( \frac{5}{3}, \ \frac{2}{3}, \ \frac{5}{3}) \ , $ and $ \ ( \frac{2}{3}, \ \frac{5}{3}, \ \frac{5}{3}) \ $ , for all of which $ \ xyz \ = \ \frac{50}{27} \ $ .

The alternative of using $ \ x \ \ne \ y \ , \ z \ = \ - 2 \lambda \ $ (and analogously for the other combinations of the three variables) produces the equation $ \ yz \ - \ 2 \cdot \left( -\frac{z}{2} \right) \cdot x \ = \ xz \ - \ 2 \cdot \left( -\frac{z}{2} \right) \cdot y \ $ $ \Rightarrow \ \ yz \ + \  xz \ = \ xz \ + \  yz \ $ , so no further information is gained.  We conclude that we have found the extremal values for the functions already and that our function has the (constrained) range $$ \ \frac{50}{27} \ \le \ f (x, \ y, \ z ) \ \le \ 2 \  \ . $$

The graph below shows the geometrical interpretation of a sphere intersected by a tilted plane, so that we are seeking extremal values of the function on a circle.  Since the function has symmetry about the line $ \ x \ = \ y \ = \ z \ $ , it may be expected that the maxima and minima number three each and are arranged symmetrically around the "constraint circle", the center of which lies at $ \ ( \frac{4}{3}, \ \frac{4}{3}, \ \frac{4}{3}) \ $ , which is connected to the appearance of $ \ \frac{4}{3} \ $ in the solution calculation using the quadratic formula in the original post.

[image: [pic to appear shortly]]

*The yellow "vertical" lines emerge at the positions of the maximal values for the function, while the red lines mark the locations of the minimal values.*