Maximize: $a+b+c$ if $ab+bc+ca=27$ and $abc=23$
Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that: $ab+bc+ca=27$ and $abc=23$,
$$\mbox{Maximize: }a+b+c$$
Can this problem be solved using only inequalities to find the maximum value of $a+b+c$ ?
Approch: For example using Schur's inequality:
$$
4(ab+bc+ca)-(a+b+c)^2\le\dfrac{9abc}{a+b+c}
$$
$$
4(27)-(a+b+c)^2\le\dfrac{9\cdot23}{a+b+c}
$$
Which does not give the maximum value of $a+b+c$.
Any hint would be appreciated.

Hint: Set up Vieta's. What's the condition to have 3 (positive) real roots?

Schur's doesn't immediately work because the equality condition is $ A=B, C=0$. So you need to reduce the variables by the current $c$ value (which means you essentially have to solve for the equality case before hand in order to proceed via Schur's).

Hint: $9 \leq (a + b + c) \left( \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \right) = (a + b + c) \left( \frac{ab + bc + ca}{abc}  \right)$.

@sudeep5221 The lower bound you get using this approach probably cannot be attained.

Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425187/abc-0-a2b2c2-1-prove-that-a2-b2-c2-le-frac154 and https://brilliant.org/wiki/cubic-discriminant/

Let's denote $p = a+b+c$, $q = ab+bc+ca = 27$ and $r = abc = 23$.
Here are the conditions for having three positive roots, that means:
$$-27r^2 + 18 pqr - 4 q^3 - 4 p^3 r + p^2 q^2 =-93015 + 11178 p + 729 p^2 - 92 p^3\ge 0 \tag{1}$$
with $p\ge0$.
Remark: The conditions can be found without using differentiation
Using WolframAlpha to solve the cubic equation of $(1)$, we deduce then
$$(1)\iff \cases{p\le \frac{-21 - 96 \sqrt 6}{23}\\\frac{-21 + 96 \sqrt 6}{23} \le p \le \frac{39}{4} }\implies \color{red}{ p \le \frac{39}{4}} \tag{2}$$
The equality of $(2)$ occurs if and only if $(a,b,c)$ are the roots of the cubic equation
$$x^3-\frac{39}{4}x^2 +27x-23 =0 \iff x \in \left\{2,2,\frac{23}{4} \right\}$$

Remark. Since it is symmetric, one often guess that the maximum and minimum both occur when two of $a, b, c$ are equal. Thus, (after some calculation) we guess that the maximum is $39/4$ when e.g. $b = c = 2, a=23/4$. But we need a rigorous proof.

WLOG, assume that $c \le 3$.
We have $ab = 23/c$, and
$23/c + c(a + b) = 27$, and
$a + b = (27 - 23/c)/c$, and
$$a + b + c = (27 - 23/c)/c + c.$$
We have
$$39/4 - a - b - c = 39/4 - ( (27 - 23/c)/c + c)$$
$$= \frac{(23-4c)(c-2)^2}{4c^2}\ge 0.$$
Thus, $39/4$ is indeed the maximum.

"We need calculus". Nope. Multiple answers give other methods.

@OscarLanzi My answer does not need Calculus. In the note, I give another method.

@OscarLanzi I delete another method to avoid confusing.

An absolutely horrendous way of approaching the given problem:
Let $a + b + c = k$. Now $a, b, c$ are the roots of $f(x):= x^3 - kx^2 + 27x - 23$, and we want three real roots. The limiting case is when we have a double root $r$, so that means $f'(r)$ $ = 3r^2 - 2kr + 27 = 0$.
Thus $27f(r) + 23f'(r) = 0$ or $27r^2 + (-27k + 69)r + (-46k + 729) = 0$ as $r \ne 0$.
Call this new polynomial $g(r)$. Thus $g(r) - 9f'(r)$ $ = -9kr - 46k + 69r + 486 = 0 \implies$ $ k = \frac{69r + 486}{9r + 46}$. Substituting this $k$ into $f'(r)$, we obtain:
$$3r^2 (9r + 46) - 2(69r + 486)r + 27(9r + 46) = 0$$
$$27r^3 + (138 - 138)r^2 + (-972 + 243)r + 1242 = 0$$
$$r^3 - 27r + 46 = 0$$
$$(r - 2)(r^2 + 2r - 23) = 0$$
$$r = 2; \ -1 \pm 2 \sqrt{6}$$
Rearranging the equation for $f'(r) = 0$ yields $\frac{3r^2 + 27}{2r} = k$. Substituting $r = -1 + 2 \sqrt{6}$ yields a value around $9.311$, and substituting $r = 2$ yields $k = \frac{39}{4}$.
Hence the maximum value is $\frac{39}{4}$.

I guess we are not allowed to use differentiation, only inequalities.

I realise the question has been tagged inequalities but I am leaving an alternative solution in the meantime, when no solutions have been proposed that use classical inequalities. (Also it helps other people know what the candidate solutions are to verify if their inequalities are sharp.)

Yes yes, no problem. Just wanted to remind about the conditon OP put. Nice job btw!

(Also it remains to verify that when $k = \frac{39}{4}$, $r = \frac{23}{2^2}$ is also a positive root so all three roots are indeed positive. There are a few small details like this which have been omitted.)

Elaborating on my comment, instead of using calculus, you could check the discriminant (algebraically) which is $-93015 + 11178 k + 729 k^2 - 92 k^3$. The condition for 3 real roots is the the discriminant is positive, which gives $k = 39/4$ upon factorization.

Maybe something less "horrendous".
We expect the sum to be maximized when one root $a=b$ is a double root and the other root $c$ is the remaining root. So we render
$a^2+2ac=27\implies \color{blue}{c=(27-a^2)/(2a)}$
$a^2c=a(27-a^2)/2=23$
Therefore
$a^3-27a+46=0$
One root is $a=2$. The residual quadratic equation is then
$a^2+2a-23=0\implies a=2\sqrt6-1$
where we require $a>0$.
Then using the eqation above in blue to obtain $c$ for each root of $a$ yields:
$a=2\implies c=23/4\implies a+b+c=2a+c=39/4$
$a=2\sqrt6-1\implies c=(25+4\sqrt6)/23\implies a+b+c=2a+c=(96\sqrt6-21)/23<219/23$
where we render $\sqrt6<5/2$. We then have $39/4=897/92$ and $219/23=876/92$, so $\color{blue}{39/4}$ represents the desired maximum.
The root $(96\sqrt6-21)/23$ represents a minimum for $a+b+c$ with all parameters positive and the equality constraints satisfied.

"We expect the sum to be maximized...": why?

Other aanswers make the same assumptiin and yet you comment my answer only. Why?
