# How to convert parametric form to implicit form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking to convert generic shapes' parametric form into their implicit form.

For instance, a sphere's:

Parametric form: $P(u,v) = ((
ρ
cos
θ
sin
ϕ
,
ρ
sin
θ
sin
ϕ
,
ρ
cos
ϕ
))$

Implicit form: $F(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1$.

I need to do this for cones, cylinders, etc. but I'm at a loss as to where to start and nothing in the equations is popping out as obvious to me. I can figure out the other shapes if I can get a little direction for the sphere.

Thanks

Comment: The parametric form for the sphere is incorrect.  You may want to check Wiki

Comment: This might be useful : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/150941/310635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plug in parametrization into implicit form to check by some trial/error if it tallies or not, seeing how sin,cos get eliminated. Basic conicoids and axisymmetric/closed/open 3D shapes have to be learnt up.

Parametrization you gave reminds one of a four cornered "samosa" snack.
[image]

Comment: ahh, samsoa, i want to eat this figure now!